# Torsions of Asymptotic Curves

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $p$ be a hyperbolic point of a surface $S$. Let $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ be two asymptotic curves passing through $p$ (in two different asymptotic directions) and assume that they have nonzero curvatures at $p$. Prove that if $\tau_1$ is the torsion of $\alpha_1$ at $p$ and $\tau_2$ is the torsion of $\alpha_2$ at $p$, then $\tau_1$ = $-\tau_2$.

I'm thinking this has to do with the fact that a hyperbolic point has negative Gaussian curvature (per http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicPoint.html) and possibly relating the principal curvatures to the asymptotic curves, but I'm not quite sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: See Exercises 17 and 18 (along with the hints) on p. 55 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). It might help in the latter problem to write the unit tangent of the asymptotic curve as $\cos\theta\mathbf e_1 +\sin\theta\mathbf e_2$, where $\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2$ are the principal directions. How are the $\theta$'s related for the two asymptotic curves?